# Access previous bot response (string) Microsoft Bot Composer

Tags: botframework, bots

I'm building a bot using Microsoft Bot Composer. I'm interested in reading a previous bot response (string value) and save it in a user.history variable. Does anyone know how can I access to it?

Best wishes,

Answer (score 0):

I'm probably missing some context as to "why" you would like to do this. A bot response string is something you write into the bot, so you could just set it equal to a variable at the start, and then use that variable later on if necessary.

Comment: Yeah, the only 2 real ways of doing this is either store _all_ responses from the bot or to store the specific response into a variable at the time of response (as you mentioned). The former would be a nightmare to try and retrieved unless it was designed in a way to make it easier.